# php file run as a cron exceeds memory allocation - works fine in browser

Tags: php, memory, cron, server, cgi

I have a php file that I can run fine by visiting the url in a browser but if I try to run it as a cronjob or via PuTTY then I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /var/www/html/admin/bv_cron.php on line 215
```

I've updated the following php.ini files:

/etc/php5/apache2 and /etc/php5/cgi

both having set memory_limit to 1024M

There are no htaccess files that alter this and no "local" php.ini files.

Apache has been restarted and the server (ubuntu) has been rebooted.

1024M is far larger than the 262144 bytes so is it not recognising this value? (the server has a max of 3GB of memory).

What could the possible issues be?

--edit--

There was a MySQL query in this file - even when this was removed to test if this was taking up memory it still came out with the error.

Comment: So `echo ini_get('memory_limit'); die();` produces the same output via Apache or CLI?

Comment: I get 1024M if I access it via my browser and 1GB if I access it via PuTTY

Comment: what is the line 215 of /var/www/html/admin/bv_cron.php ?